# In App Purchase Signature Verification Failed Error in Android using Cordova

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am using the following plugin for In-App Purchase in Cordova
"https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase"

Getting Error of

> Signature Failed Code 1003

in alpha testing, added Billing Key in manifest.json file also.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're referring is not maintained anymore. You should probably try with this one:

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

which is more popular and actively maintained.